# Is it off-topic to ask about rationale behind political satire?

Tags: discussion

I want to know what does a joke about an existing politician from an SNL skit refer to. Is this community an appropriate place to ask? Another one I'm considering is Movies&TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a precedent for such a question: [Explanation of John Oliver's jokes about countries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11319/explanation-of-john-olivers-jokes-about-countries)

The question currently has a score of +4/-1 and an accepted answer with +5/-0

Comment: also: [What's the explanation behind Obama's joke about Bernie Sanders?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11253/101)

Answer (score 2):

1. It *probably* would be on-topic for the site.

   It's about politics. It requires political expertise to answer, possibly (see #2). And it's actually practical in the same way "identification" questions are practical on M&TV and SFF and Music.
2. It *probably* would be an awful low-quality question, if the answer is easily Googleable. Depends on specific question, really.

   (Doesn't mean it wouldn't likely get 100 upvotes due to bikeshedding effect, if it gets on HNQ, especially if, like 99% comedians' jokes, it's at the expense of Republican politician).

Comment: Having said that, my worry is that if we allow such questions, people would use that fact as a tacit permission to simply popularize non-ending stream of jokes, either for political propaganda reasons or just rep-gathering. But that concern isn't really a valid basis to make something out of scope on a site, imho.