# Why is an insulting, abusive Meme allowed to remain?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We already have a question about [memes in general](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/should-memes-be-allowed-in-questions). That question brought my attention to the [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82300/why-is-the-muslim-world-focusing-on-israels-conflict-with-the-palestinians-yet) one. When I first viewed the question, I was shocked that the meme had been allowed to remain. I added a polite, properly referenced, and thorough explanation regarding why it was highly insulting.

I pointed out that Joe Biden, a staunch supporter of Israel, had called Israel's bombing campaign [indiscriminate](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-67699255). I also pointed out that Human Rights Watch, a large independent organisation, had raised credible concerns about Israel's use of [phosphorous bombs](https://www.hrw.org/news/2023/10/12/israel-white-phosphorus-used-gaza-lebanon) in the current campaign. I provided these as just two examples of IDF abuses in the current war (there are of course many others I could have cited). I explained that given these abuses, it is an insult to the family and loved ones of Gaza's many dead civilians to claim that Israel is merely "defending itself".

I was even more upset to find that my reasoned comment was deleted but the offensive meme allowed to remain. Can a moderator please explain why this is the case? I understand that there is a place for memes, but not where they are gratuitously offensive. If the meme is to remain, then surely it is only right that a reasoned critique of it should also be allowed to remain too?

Edit: to make clear I have flagged this post as "Rude and Abusive", but to date no action has been taken. The flag was rejected with the odd comment:

> Declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
> content that requires their intervention.

Well yes, this meme *does* require moderator intervention thank you.

Comment: Have you flagged the post and explain the issue you have with the meme?

Comment: I have indeed. Flag was ignored / rejected (not sure how to tell which).

Comment: I would include that fact and what the message on the resolution says as that will likely influence any responses you get.

Comment: If you go into your profile there is a link shows your flagging history and you can see status and results of every flag that you have raised. However it should be noted that a rude and abusive flag might not have been the best choice and choosing the one for moderator attention would have been better as you could explain exactly what you see is wrong with the post.

Comment: I have thoroughly looked through my profile and still can't find flagging history. Does it only appear after a certain amount of reputation? In the past I have raised moderator attention flags and had them rejected because it "reduces moderator time if I use one of the preexisting flags" or some such.

Comment: I've even done a ctrl + f and searched for "flag" on my profile. No luck.

Comment: Try this link, I have edited it to be your userid and you will be the only one able to use it. https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/48175

Comment: Thank you, that worked

Comment: Just realised that I may have misunderstood the rejection comment. Is it saying that I should just edit the post myself? If that is the case, it should have been written more clearly. As a new user I am not familiar with the ettiquetes of editing and when it is permitted.

Comment: Editing the question to remove it would be a good start and if it gets put back in a flag would be more appropriate. Though make sure you clearly explain why you removed it in the edit explanation box including why you find it offensive.

Comment: There is already a meta discussion about that particular image in that particular question. Please don't start a second one.

Comment: @Philipp, that question is about memes in general and whether they ought to be allowed. This is about this particular meme and why it needs to be removed.

Comment: @political_noob Both of the upvoted answers on the duplicate questions directly address this particular case. Read them, and if you don't agree, post an answer of your own.